# bind mixamo bone to unity

Tags: unity

I download the mixamo character bone and rig it in the blender. and then use it in unity. but it seen no match in unity?

I change the mesh in skinmeshrenderer and the mesh disappears?

But I use mixamo auto rigging, and replace the mesh in Skinmeshrenderer it's work find.(the mesh no disappears in skinmeshrenderer)

[image]

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What does "it's work find" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement a Mixamo animation in Unity, you can use the auto-rigging from Unity, if you don't know how to skin animation to the mesh. You'll have to follow the next steps.

**Mixamo Download**

1. Upload your character FBX:
   [image: Upload your character FBX]
2. Select an animation:
   [image: Select an animation]
3. Click on Download, and do the next settings:
   [image: Click on Download, and do the next settings]

**Unity Procedure**

After importing your animation in Unity, you'll see a weird movement, on your character, that's because of the rig, so we'll have to change that.

1. That's how your rig panel on your animation should look like, Humanoid, and Copy the avatar from the mesh you just uploaded on Mixamo:
   [image: That's how your rig panel on your animation should look like]
2. Weird animation movement ? Yea, that happens sometimes, in order to fix that you'll have to play with this values around (
   I know it's a little vague, but there are no fixed standards, you turn them all on, put them on Original, and then turn off what's wrong):
   [image: Play with this values around]